# How to create custom CSS for dynamic-named DIV

Tags: html, css

I want to restrict content height of external DIV loaded to website through ad, it is too big and I want to limit height of that div element.

Issue is that every time on refresh, that DIV has new name, for example:

First load:

`<div id="vdzw_9waM"></div>`

Second load:

`<div id="vdzw_6tzW"></div>`

Third load:

`<div id="vdzw_2tpSd"></div>`

and so on...

Any idea how to override this? Thank you

I tried common CSS, but because div id is dynamically populated every time with different name, I could not implement any CSS rule.

EDIT:

I tried to manipulate with CSS of the element which contains this ID, but no success...only impact on CSS which changes layout of this ID is to change CSS of this particular ID

Comment: Are you able to identify the element the dynamic advert loads into?

Comment: I am sorry, I did not understand question, could you clarify, please...

Comment: If you mean by that - container which contains ad, yes - I am using AdvancedAds for WP and video is loaded inside that container, but if I manipulate with container CSS that does not impact on video inside @DavidThomas

Comment: if you give full html i can write correct selector

Comment: hey @PetePearl I can give you link to the post page, where you can see video and inspect element to see by your self. Only one notice - content renders only for USA, so if you are outside USA, you need to be on VPN :)

Comment: Is it possible to apply a CSS class to the div that the ad loads into rather than attempting to target by id?

Comment: @RiverTam I tried that already, with no sucess - even I applied CSS to the outer div, ad layout stays unchanged

Comment: can you give me link please

Answer (score 0):

If the `id` pattern is consistent-- as it is in the examples you supplied-- you could apply your styles by partial id match:

```
div[id^='vdzw'] {
    max-height: 500px;
}
```

That selector will apply the `max-height` to all `div` elements that have an `id` starting with (`^=`) "vdzw".

A more reliable way is to ensure your ads get rendered into a container that you define, and then set the styles based on selectors that identify the container you've defined.

Comment: Thank you @Marc, but I am not very good with JavaScript, that is not something I can understand "on first", could you please elaborate above code a little bit more?

Comment: I used your example - but no success - video still renders without changes. I cleared cache, of course in browser and on server. I already tried CSS on container where ad renders - no success - I shrink container, but ads still loads with same div and outside the container.